# Show that a space $H$ is Hilbert.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let
\begin{equation}
H = \{f \in L^2(0,\infty):\int_0^\infty f^2(x)e^{-x}dx \lt\infty\}
\end{equation}

Show that $H$ is a Hilbert space with scalar product
\begin{equation}
\langle f,g \rangle = \int_0^\infty f(x)g(x)e^{-x}dx
\end{equation}

I was trying to show that it is complete about the norm coming from scalar product, but I think it's way too difficult. Instead, I was thinking to define a Unitary isomorphism between $H$ and $L^2(0,\infty)$ like this:
\begin{equation}
U:H\rightarrow L^2(0,\infty)
\end{equation}

such that $\langle U(f),U(g)\rangle_{L^2}$ = $\langle f,g\rangle_{H}$.

The idea is that the scala product on $H$ is really similar to $L^2$ 's one.
Any suggestions on how to define it properly?

Comment: $f \mapsto (x \mapsto e^{-x/2} f(x))$ springs to mind.

Comment: Simply because I'm dealing with these things for the first time. Thank you

Comment: @TheoBendit you proebably mean $e^{x/2}f(x)$ right?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy not quite.  He is defining it as the subspace of $L^2(\lambda)$ ($\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $(0,\infty)$) which is also in $L^2(\mu)$, and using the $L^2(\mu)$-norm, so it is "missing" things which can blow up subexponentially at infinity, therefore cannot be complete in $L^2(\mu)$.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks for your comment. I was wrong and I have deleted my comment.

Comment: @JamesArten No, I mean what I wrote, at least in the context of how $U$ is defined in your question. With my definition, you have $$\langle U(f), U(g) \rangle_{L^2} = \int_0^\infty e^{-x/2}f(x)e^{-x/2}g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^\infty e^{-x}f(x)g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \langle f, g\rangle_H.$$

Comment: @JamesArten P.S. `\langle` and `\rangle` produce $\langle$ and $\rangle$ respectively.

Comment: @JamesArten As Kavi Rama Murthy's example shows, the map $U$ is not an isomorphism. In particular,  this map is not surjective, as the function $e^{-x/2} \in L^2$ has no preimage.

Comment: This is false. My conjecture is you gave the definition of $H$ wrong; is $H = \{f \in L^2(0,\infty):\int_0^\infty f^2(x)e^{-x}dx \lt\infty\}$ _exactly_ how $H$ was defined in the statement of the problem?

Comment: See, that seems like a silly definition, because it just says $H=L^2((0,\infty))$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich yes the exercise states exactly this.. I found actually another version of it where we have $H = \{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow(0,+\infty): \int_0^\infty f^2(x)e^{-x}dx < \infty\}$

Comment: That second version is even sillier, because the second $H$ is not even a vector space. Unless maybe you meant $f:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$.

Comment: that's what I meant.. sorry.

Comment: Right. Given that your statement of the second version was _so_ totally wrong, I find it hard to believe that you've reproduced the first version correctly.

Comment: I checked that. It is correct. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4):

I think this is false. $\{I_{(0,n)}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $H$ which is not convergent. If this sequence converges in $H$ then some sequence converges almost everywhere w.r.t. $e^{-x}dx$ hence w.r.t. Lebesgue measure and the limit has to be $1$ almost everywhere w.r.t. Lebesgue measure. But then the limit is not in $L^{2}(0,\infty)$, hence not in $H$.

Comment: That sequence is not cauchy, is it?

Comment: It is Cauchy ln the norm of H.

Comment: Is $I_{(0, n)}$ the indicator function for the interval $(0, n)$? If so, doesn't this converge to the constant function $1$?

Comment: No wait, +1, I see my error. The indicator function doesn't belong to $H$ as $H$ consists only of functions already in $L^2(0, \infty)$. I agree: this is not a Hilbert Space.

Comment: Sorry but if the sequence $I_{(0,n)}$ is not in $H$ from the beginning, does it make sense to consider it to say that the space is not Hilbert? Probably a dumb question but I have to say again that it's the first time I'm studying this.

Comment: @JamesArten What makes you think $I_{(0,n)}$ is not in $H$?

Comment: Sorry of course it is in $H$ I was thinking about letting $n \rightarrow \infty$ but of course $\chi_{0,n}$ belongs to $L^2$ as long as $n$ is finite.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy can you explain better why the sequence shouldn't be convergent in $H$?

Comment: @JamesArten We know, or should know, that if $f_n\to f$ in $L^2(\mu)$ then some subsequence tends to $f$ almost everywhere. Hence if the given $f_n$ have a limit in $H$ the llimit must be $1$. But $1\notin H$.

Answer (score -1):

Ok this is what I got in the end:

Again, we have

\begin{equation}
H = \{f \in L^2(0,\infty): \int_0^\infty f^2(x)e^{-x}dx < \infty\}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\langle f,g \rangle_{H} = \int_0^\infty f(x)g(x)e^{-x}dx
\end{equation}

So, (I guess),
\begin{equation}
||f||_H = \sqrt{\langle f,f \rangle_{H}} = \left(\int_0^\infty f^2(x)e^{-x}dx \right)^{1/2}
\end{equation}

Taking $f_n = \chi_{(0,n)}$ we have $f_n \in L^2(0,\infty) \forall n$ and it is Cauchy in $H$ because, assuming $n >m$ we could consider
\begin{equation}
||\chi_{(0,n)}-\chi_{(0,m)}||_H = ||\chi_{(m,n)}||_H = \int_m^n e^{-x}dx = -e^{-n}+e^{-m}<\epsilon
\end{equation}
For $m,n$ sufficiently large. And also
\begin{equation}
||\chi_{(0,n)}-\chi_{(0,\infty)}||_H = \int_0^\infty (\chi_{(0,n)}-\chi_{(0,\infty)})^2e^{-x}dx < \infty
\end{equation}

Which step could be wrong?

I'm sorry for my mistakes, I'm here to learn, and also to find people to talk over with.

Thank you

Comment: What step could be wrong? What's wrong is you seem to be ignoring the other posted answer and comments. There's no suuch thing as $||\chi_{(0,n)}-\chi_{(0,\infty)}||_H$ because $\chi_{(0,n)}-\chi_{(0,\infty)}$ is not an element of $H$.